# How to allow editing of templates for email by admin user in Django?

Tags: python, django

I need to allow the admin user to make an email template in html, and the user should be able to add dynamic variables where needed. The template will be saved in the database. For example,

```
Dear {{user.first_name}},
        Thanks for participating in our cooking class on {{cooking_class.date}}
```

Then, there will be a cron job which will send emails and fill the dynamic variables.
What are my options? Is there a django package for this? I am using Django 1.4.3

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar, here's what I did:

1. Create an app, and registered a model to store the email
2. Set up a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/) to process the email
3. Manage the cron job via [django-chronograph](http://code.google.com/p/django-chronograph/)

Rendering the email, I used [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut), for example

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from myproject.myemailapp.models import EmailTpl

email_tpl = EmailTpl.objects.get(...#criteria here)
# fetch the rest of your dynamic variables

rendered_tpl = render_to_string(email_tpl.user_entered_tpl, {
    "user": user,
    "cooking_class": cooking_class,
    # ... and so on
})
```

Alternatively, [Django Packages has some packages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/email/) you might want to look into. Would be great if you post back the route you decided.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [django-dbtemplates](https://github.com/jazzband/django-dbtemplates) allows you to store templates in your database, and you can expose the dbtemplate app on your Admin site to edit.  You can set your middleware settings such that either the database template or the same template in other locations has priority for loading.

We are using this in a project to manage templates for different products, with the database-stored template for each product linked by ForeignKey.